# Mathmod: coding complex equation

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I was wondering how I can code the formula below in LaTeX without the need for using the `amsmath` package!

[Equation](https://ibb.co/e4KWbG)

Comment: Please do not post only images, but your code too (minimal, compilable example; MWE).

Comment: Plus the image does not work

Comment: @daleif The image problem is sorted now!

Comment: @RezaJabal it is still not a good idea to use images, if yo do, use the system that the site provides, many users will not go to external resources. Also you should show what you have already, other wise this question will be labelled as a "do it for me" question, which is generally downvoted. Besides this, the formula you show is rather basic, and any decent LaTeX introduction will teach you all the components needed to make this. You don't even need `amsmath` to do so, this is basic math.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What do wish to avoid loading the `amsmath` package?

Comment: @Mico Thank you for asking this. For some reason when I use asmatch package it totally mess with my tables and my document fails to compile. I spent a considerable amount of time figuring out what might be the problem, but I did not manage to resolve the issue. Consequently I decided not to use asmath package in my whole document which is really limiting!

Comment: Then you should probably investigate more why it does not work. Perhaps with our help. Usually we do not have any issues with tables vs `amsmath`, but get cannot day for sure without knowing more about your document. It might also be because you are using solutions you really shouldn't (there are many bad latex resources out there)

Comment: If you have any math in a latex more complicated than `$x$` then you should be using `amsmath` the only reason that isn't in the format by default is the memory requirements of a PC in 1990.

Answer (score 4):

> ... when I use the `amsmath` package it totally mess[es] with my tables ...

Since `table` and `tabular`-like environments aren't really affected by code provided by the `amsmath` package, you may want to take some time to re-examine the validity of whatever conclusions you've drawn to date regarding the usability and usefulness of the `amsmath` package.

One of the really useful aspects of the `amsmath` package is that it provides all kinds of environments and methods for introducing linebreaks in long displayed formulas. While the formula you're looking to typeset *could* conceivably fit on one line, the formula can be made far more readable by (a) introducing a suitably chosen linebreak by (b) using a `\smash[b]` directive over the large operators in the first row, to snug up the two rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for '\smash[b]` macro and 'split' environment
\usepackage{newtxtext} % optional (Times Roman text font)
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2} % optional (Times Roman math font)

\begin{document}
\[
\mathcal{L}(\alpha)=\prod_{i=1}^M\sum_{g_i^1}\sum_{g_i^2}
\Bigl\{ \prod_{j=1}^{R_i} \sum_{e_{ij}} 
\bigl[(1-\alpha)P(b_{ij}\mid g_i^1,e_{ij})
+\alpha P(b_{ij}\mid g_i^2,e_{ij})\bigr]
P(e_{ij}) \Bigr\} P(g_i^2) P(g_i^1)
\]

\[
\begin{split}
\mathcal{L}(\alpha)=\smash[b]{\prod_{i=1}^M\sum_{g_i^1}\sum_{g_i^2}
\Bigl\{ \prod_{j=1}^{R_i} \sum_{e_{ij}}} 
\bigl[(1-\alpha)&P(b_{ij}\mid g_i^1,e_{ij})\\
{}+\alpha &P(b_{ij}\mid g_i^2,e_{ij})\bigr]
P(e_{ij}) \Bigr\} P(g_i^2) P(g_i^1)
\end{split}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you don't have access to the `mtpro2` package consider loading `mathptmx` instead of `newtxtext` and `mtpro2`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments and blatant criticism over "do it for me" impression you got from this question. Comments from Mico and daleif were really helpful, however I came up with this simplistic solution that seems doesn't require `amsmath` package:

```
\begin{equation}
    \zeta(\alpha)=\prod_{i=1}^{M} \sum_{g_{i}^{1}} \sum_{g_{i}^{2}} \Bigg\{\prod_{j=1}^{R} \sum_{e_{ij}} \Big(\big(1 - \alpha\big)P\big(b_{ij} | g_{i}^{1},e_{ij}\big) + \alpha P\big(b_{ij} | g_{i}^{2},e_{ij}\big)\Big) P\big(e_{ij}\big)\Bigg\} P(g_{i}^2)P(g_{i}^2)
\end{equation}\label{eq:freemix}
```

Comment: My guess for how to write the first symbol would have been `\mathcal{L}`, not `\zeta`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks a lot. I was struggling with this!